# Define module as feature

Tags: console

Creating a module with Drupal Composer asks me:

> Define module as feature (yes/no)

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

That option will add some code to the generated module to make it a [Feature](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module - a module that provides some exportable configuration.

More info: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/features/creating-and-configuring-bundles
Source: https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/blob/master/src/Generator/ModuleGenerator.php#L94

Answer (score 3):

It just adds a file with the name of the feature bundle, and the feature bundle is nothing but a way to group features.

With this file your module will appear on the features list.

[image]